# Single Sign On using SpringBoot and LDAP server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap

I have to design a Single Sign on in my web application. The requirement is to provide the seamless login experience to the user. In my company when user logged into the system they are seamlessly connected to the applications like - internal applications, chat messenger, outlook. Similarly I have to implement the single sign on for the users. When user access the application, it should not ask user to login and validate the user AD group info and authenticate it. Lets say if few users are assigned to a particular AD group then they only will have the access to the application. Other AD groups will not have the access to the application and when they try to access the application link, error page should be displayed.

Ex: User belongs to AD group 'ABC' - Will have the access to the application
    User belongs to AD group 'XYZ' - Show error message on the web page

My questions are

1. How would I detect the user who has logged into the system? If i detect the user I need to connect to the LDAP to verify the valid AD group for the user?
2. AD group info resides in LDAP server of the company. What all details I can get from LDAP?
3. I am using SpringBoot application and Tomcat Linux server for deployment

Please help/suggest how to design and implement this?

Comment: Hi, how did you implement this? Could you please share the details?

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways to do this is using JWTs. (Refer https://jwt.io/)

After the authentication, you can issue a JWT as a result of successful authentication. This JWT can contain multiple things like username / other user info, user roles/permissions e.g. in your case it contain list of AD groups it has access to.

Now all you have to do is, send this JWT alongwith each request and put a filter (maybe through Spring security) to allow/disallow the user by validating JWT.

For the last part, most of the configuration is provided by Spring security out of the box, so there is not much you would have to implement on your own.

Comment: thanks for the details. In my case, we dnt want to display the login form to the user. Instead by some way we have to detect the username from the windows system or intranet. After detecting username we need to send this username to the LDAP for authentication. I am not sure how to detect the username from system or intranet. Also not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Even if you find a way to retrieve the username from system/intranet, what will you do just with username. For authenticating the user with username you will need to have password as well. that's why I suggested JWT. You won't be needing a password with JWT. And you can keep the username inside JWT itself. I suggested form login for first time login only. On subsequent logins(i.e. till the session does not expire) user won't see the form but would be auto-logged in using JWT.

Comment: How do you send this JWT to the spring app? You said to send it with each request, do you mean as a cookie?

Comment: Also, is it the LDAP server the one who should issue the JWT?

Comment: @DanielFacciabene Standard way to send JWT is in request header. Your client should send the JWT in `Authorization` header as bearer token.